# How to implement this menu using css pseudo-class selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have developed a menu, but I want to add some keyboard functionality to the menu. When the menu is focused, I would like to be able to press <kbd>enter</kbd> to show the menu. Then I would be able to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the menu items. Then I want to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to hide the menu items.

How do I change my CSS?

HTML

```
<ul class="hMenu">
  <li><a href="">prod1</a>
    <div>
      <a href="">test1</a>
      <a href="">test2</a>
      <a href="">test3</a>                  
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" >prod2</a>
    <div>
      <a href="">test4</a>  
      <a href="">test5</a>                  
    </div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.hMenu li:hover a {
  color:red;
}           
ul.hMenu  { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  z-index: 1;               
}
ul.hMenu li  {  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width:140px;
}
ul.hMenu li a { 
  display: block; 
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none
}          
ul.hMenu li div  {                    
  position: absolute;               
  display: none;                
}
ul.hMenu div a {
  background: yellow;     
}
ul.hMenu li :hover   {
  background: yellow
}
/**Mouse hover the menus can show up**/
ul.hMenu li:hover div{          
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can do this without js

Comment: I agree with @fattomhk there are the :active and :focus pseudo selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus The :active only seems to work when the primary mouse button is down, and the :focus only seems to be applied when the element has keyboard focus. For what you are asking using JavaScript to change the classes would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution that will get you going in the right direction.

CSS can not deal with events that have to do with specific keys that are typed. You will need to use javascript, or in this case jQuery, to help you out.

The `keypress` function is what you are looking for in this situation.

I am not sure how to do the tabbing feature, but I did get the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd> features to work

Here is the jQuery

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var menu = $(".hMenu");
    menu.hide()
    $("body").on("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { //Key Code for Enter
            menu.fadeIn();
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { //Key Code for ESC
            menu.fadeOut();
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 9) { //Key Code for Tab
            //Tabbing function here
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Tra/)

This will effectively fade the menu in and out when you press the respective key.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply,I mean when I focus on the menu and press enter then the menu items will show up.

Comment: So you want to click on the top menu items, then press enter to show the sub menu?

Comment: Yes,and then click the ESC will hidden the sub menu.Also we can use the Tab to select the sub menu items.